# Replace string parameters with an array value by index

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

is there some native php which recieves a string and an array as parameters and replaces array's indexes w/ their respective values inside the string?

Something like:

```
$myString = "{days} days left for {holiday}";
$params = array(
    "days" => 275,
    "holiday" => "Christmas"
);
echo _some_function($myString, $params);
//Outputs: "275 days left for Christmas"
```

Comment: Here you go: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php Maybe you can surprise yourself and solve the problem yourself :D!

Comment: Good point @Rizier123 :) ! But what if the input string contains more than 1 ocurrence on "days" word? I updated my example

Comment: You could build a basic version of this with `sprintf` (without named params), or you could use `preg_replace_callback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just first add the delimiters around the keys and then just use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) to replace the values)

```
<?php

    $myString = "{days} days left for {holiday}";
    $delimiters = ["{", "}"];
    $params = [
        "days" => 275,
        "holiday" => "Christmas"
    ];

    function someCrazyFunction($myString, $params, $delimiters) {
        foreach($params as $k => $v) {
            $params[$delimiters[0] . $k . $delimiters[1]] = $v;
            unset($params[$k]);
        }

        return strtr($myString, $params);

    }


    echo someCrazyFunction($myString, $params, $delimiters);

?>
```

output:

```
275 days left for Christmas
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_some_function($myString, $params){
   foreach($params as $k=>$v)
        $myString = str_replace("{".$k."}",$v,$mString);
   return $myString;
}
```

-dont ask:What if  "days" has somthing like "holiday" as value ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers.
According to @Rizier123 and @superduperawesomephpexpert comments:

```
$myString = "{days} days left for {holiday}";
$params = array(
    "days" => 275,
    "holiday" => "Christmas"
);

$indexes = array_map(function($v){
    return '{'.$v.'}';
}, array_keys($params));

echo str_replace($indexes, $params, $myString);
```

Comment: Well just to warn you, if you use `str_replace()` and lets say you have `days => holiday123` then `holiday` will get replaced again from `holiday => Christmas`, that's why I used `strtr` in my answer that this doesn't happen, just to let you know! (BTW: Cool that you have figured out a solution yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Rizier123. I will accept your answer as soon as its avaliable. (y)